# pandas multiindex assignment from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, variable-assignment, multi-index

I am trying to understand `pandas` `MultiIndex` `DataFrame`s and how to assign data to them. Specifically I'm interested in assigning entire blocks that match another smaller data frame.

```
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=ix, columns=['1st', '2nd', '3rd'], dtype=np.float64)
df_ = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=['1st', '2nd', '3rd'], data=np.random.rand(4, 3))
df_

    1st     2nd     3rd
a   0.730251    0.468134    0.876926
b   0.104990    0.082461    0.129083
c   0.993608    0.117799    0.341811
d   0.784950    0.840145    0.016777
```

`df` is the same except that all the values are `NaN` and there are two blocks `A` and `B`. Now if I want to assign the values from `df_` to `df` I would imagine I can do something like

```
df.loc['A',:] = df_                # Runs, does not work
df.loc[('A','a'):('A','d')] = df_  # AssertionError (??) 'Start slice bound is non-scalar'
df.loc[('A','a'):('A','d')]        # No AssertionError (??)

idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx['A', :]] = df_          # Runs, does not work
```

None of these work, they leave all the values in `df` as `NaN`, although `df.loc[idx['A', :]]` gives me a slice of the data frame that exactly matches that of the sub frame (`df_`). So is this a case of setting values on a view? Explicitly iterating over the index in `df_` works

```
# this is fine
for v in df_.index:
    df.loc[idx['A', v]] = df_.loc[v]

# this is also fine
for v in df_.index:
    df.loc['A', v] = df_.loc[v]
```

Is it even possible to assign whole blocks like this (sort of like `NumPy`)? If not, that's fine, I am simply trying to understand how the system works.

There's a related question about index slicers, but it's about assigning a single value to a masked portion of the `DataFrame`, not about assigning blocks.
[Pandas : Proper way to set values based on condition for subset of multiindex dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002197/pandas-proper-way-to-set-values-based-on-condition-for-subset-of-multiindex-da)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you use

```
df.loc['A', :] = df_
```

Pandas tries to align the index of `df_` with the index of a sub-DataFrame of
`df`.  However, at the [point in the code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L436) where alignment is performed, the
sub-DataFrame has a **MultiIndex**, not the single index you see as the result
of `df.loc['A', :]`.

So the alignment fails because `df_` has a single index, not the MultiIndex that
is needed. To see that the index of `df_` is indeed the problem, note that

```
ix_ = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']])
df_.index = ix_
df.loc['A', :] = df_
print(df)
```

succeeds, yielding something like

```
A a  0.229970  0.730824  0.784356
  b  0.584390  0.628337  0.318222
  c  0.257192  0.624273  0.221279
  d  0.787023  0.056342  0.240735
B a       NaN       NaN       NaN
  b       NaN       NaN       NaN
  c       NaN       NaN       NaN
  d       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Of course, you probably do not want to have to create a new MultiIndex every
time you want to assign a block of values. So instead, to work around this
alignment problem, you can use a NumPy array as the assignment value:

```
df.loc['A', :] = df_.values
```

Since `df_.values` is a NumPy array and an array has no index, [no alignment is
performed](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L440)
and the assignment yields the same result as above. This trick of using a NumPy arrays when you don't want alignment of indexes
applies to many situations when using Pandas.

Note also that assignment-by-NumPy-array can also help you perform more complicated assignments such as to rows which are not contiguous:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:,('a','b')], :] = df_.values
```

yields

```
In [85]: df
Out[85]: 
          1st       2nd       3rd
A a  0.229970  0.730824  0.784356
  b  0.584390  0.628337  0.318222
  c       NaN       NaN       NaN
  d       NaN       NaN       NaN
B a  0.257192  0.624273  0.221279
  b  0.787023  0.056342  0.240735
  c       NaN       NaN       NaN
  d       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

for example.

Comment: I see that's a good explanation, thanks. I like the `df_.values`, especially because it allows you to do all kinds of crazy partial assignments. Just need to be careful to index the data frames in the same order, I was wondering why some of my data suddenly flips around (oops).

Comment: If the order of the values is different then it might be easiest to make the index of `df_` a MultiIndex and let Pandas deal with the alignment for you.

Comment: The order was different because I was being stupid, but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

I did [8480](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8480) a while back, which makes sub-frame assignment with columns work. so, you may do as follows as a work-around:

```
>>> rf
     1st    2nd    3rd
a  0.730  0.468  0.877
b  0.105  0.082  0.129
c  0.994  0.118  0.342
d  0.785  0.840  0.017
>>> df.T['A'] = rf.T  # take transpose of both sides
>>> df
       1st    2nd    3rd
A a  0.730  0.468  0.877
  b  0.105  0.082  0.129
  c  0.994  0.118  0.342
  d  0.785  0.840  0.017
B a    NaN    NaN    NaN
  b    NaN    NaN    NaN
  c    NaN    NaN    NaN
  d    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

that said, you may want to post this as a bug on github.

**edit**: seems that adding a dummy slice at the end also works:

```
>>> df.loc['A'][:] = rf
>>> df
       1st    2nd    3rd
A a  0.730  0.468  0.877
  b  0.105  0.082  0.129
  c  0.994  0.118  0.342
  d  0.785  0.840  0.017
B a    NaN    NaN    NaN
  b    NaN    NaN    NaN
  c    NaN    NaN    NaN
  d    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: doesn't the dummy index at the end create a `view` of the data frame as documented [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) - I at least get the warning about assigning values to a view

Comment: The suggestion after the edit worked for me, thank you!