Assignment with .loc on a multiindex gives nan values if there are only two levels?
When selecting part of a multiindex of a Pandas Dataframe or series, assigning to this selection using values of a similarly indexed frame gives nan if the multiindex only has two levels, while the same operation gives actual values on a standard index or multiindex with more levels. What is the proper way to consistently assign to a slice of a multiindex?
Example:
import sys
from importlib.metadata import version

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

print(f"Python version: {sys.version}")
print(f"Pandas version: {version('pandas')}")
print(f"Numpy version: {version('numpy')}\n")

s = pd.Series(np.random.random(5), index=pd.Index(np.arange(5)))
s.loc[0] += 1
print(f"A. Standard index: .loc[0]\n{s}\n")

s_multi_3 = pd.Series(np.random.random(5), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["a"], ["b"], np.arange(5)]))
s_multi_2 = s_multi_3.droplevel(0)

s_multi_2.loc[:, [0]] += 1
print(f"B1. Multi index - 2 levels: .loc[:, [0]]\n{s_multi_2}\n")
s_multi_2.loc[:, 0] += 1
print(f"C1. Multi index - 2 levels: .loc[:, 0]\n{s_multi_2}\n")

s_multi_3.loc[:, :, [0]] += 1
print(f"B2. Multi index - 3 levels: .loc[:, :, [0]]\n{s_multi_3}\n")
s_multi_3.loc[:, :, 0] += 1
print(f"C2. Multi index - 3 levels: .loc[:, :, 0]\n{s_multi_3}\n")

Output:
Python version: 3.12.5 (tags/v3.12.5:ff3bc82, Aug  6 2024, 20:45:27) [MSC v.1940 64 bit (AMD64)]
Pandas version: 2.2.2
Numpy version: 2.0.1

A. Standard index: .loc[0]
0    1.184514
1    0.460907
2    0.777756
3    0.983770
4    0.722276
dtype: float64

B1. Multi index - 2 levels: .loc[:, [0]]
b  0    1.865925
   1    0.728489
   2    0.948691
   3    0.786609
   4    0.756799
dtype: float64

C1. Multi index - 2 levels: .loc[:, 0]
b  0         NaN
   1    0.728489
   2    0.948691
   3    0.786609
   4    0.756799
dtype: float64

B2. Multi index - 3 levels: .loc[:, :, [0]]
a  b  0    1.865925
      1    0.728489
      2    0.948691
      3    0.786609
      4    0.756799
dtype: float64

C2. Multi index - 3 levels: .loc[:, :, 0]
a  b  0    2.865925
      1    0.728489
      2    0.948691
      3    0.786609
      4    0.756799
dtype: float64

Why does only C1 give a NaN ??

The safer way would be to ensure the slice has the same number of levels as the source dataframe - this is what you achieved by selecting a list.

Yes that is what I ended up doing, but why do the results vary depending on the number of levels when not using a list ? Is it expected behaviour ? I could not find anything in the docs mentioning it was a bad practice to assign values this way, did I miss it somehow ?

Maybe this can help ... It boils down to alignment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28432733/7175713
