# How to filter through pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivot table created from pandas (DataFrame object).

Currently, I have multiple indexes and I want to be able to filter through some of them. To clarify this is how the pivot tables looks like.

[image]

There are 1000s of those. What I want to be able to do is get all the instances where opt_step is 1, cf is `pv_area_cost1a` and when the optimization is MANHATTAN. The end goal is to be able to graph iterations vs cost for some instances.

The pivot table is called pt. I've tried `pt.index.get_level_values['pv_area_cost1a']` and I have read the entire page in advanced indexing to no avail.

Comment: Isnt' 'get_level_values' a function? Also the the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) say it should be an int, but indeed I seem to remember using it with column labels

Comment: I'm sorry, the get_level_values function returns all the values of a specific index. For example, cf has pv_area_cost1a, full_cost, and several more cfs. Some of the example on the docs says you should be able to retrieve values for a specific index with pt['pv_area_cost1a'] but it does not.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002197/pandas-proper-way-to-set-values-based-on-condition-for-subset-of-multiindex-da) question can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a multi-indexed dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'i1': [1, 1, 1, 1], 'i2': [2, 2, 3, 3], 'i3': [4, 5, 4, 5], 'v1': [10] * 4, 'v2': [20] * 4}).set_index(['i1', 'i2', 'i3'])
>>> df
          v1  v2
i1 i2 i3        
1  2  4   10  20
      5   10  20
   3  4   10  20
      5   10  20
```

For me, the easiest way to slice this type of dataframe is to use a combination of `.loc` and `IndexSlice`.  So, to slice the above df where `i2=3` and `i3=5`:

```
>>> df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 3, 5], :]

          v1  v2
i1 i2 i3        
1  3  5   10  20
```

The `:` inside `IndexSlice` signifies to select all rows of `i1`.  The very last `:` inside the `loc` function signifies to select all columns in the dataframe (`v1` and `v2`).

Comment: This was great! Thanks for the help.

Comment: It says my reputation has to be > 15. 

I will certainly up vote you once I am at 15.