# Setting values with multiindex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

There are already a couple of questions on SO relating to this, most notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002197/pandas-proper-way-to-set-values-based-on-condition-for-subset-of-multiindex-da), however none of the answers seem to work for me and quite a few links to docs (especially on lexsorting) are broken, so I'll ask another one.

I'm trying do to something (seemingly) very simple. Consider the following MultiIndexed Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd; import random
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
      ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index), pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index)], axis=1)
```

Now I want to set all values in column `0` to some value (say `np.NaN`) for the observations in category `one`. I've failed with:

```
df.loc(axis=0)[:, "one"][0] = 1 # setting with copy warning
```

and

```
df.loc(axis=0)[:, "one", 0] = 1
```

which either yields a warning about length of keys exceeding length of index, or one about a lack of lexsorting to sufficient depth.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with tuple for selecting `MultiIndex` and `0` for selecting column:

```
import pandas as pd; 
import random
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
      ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]

#add for testing
np.random.seed(0)
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index), pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index)], axis=1)
```

```
print df
                     0         1
first second                    
bar   one     1.764052 -0.103219
      two     0.400157  0.410599
baz   one     0.978738  0.144044
      two     2.240893  1.454274
foo   one     1.867558  0.761038
      two    -0.977278  0.121675
qux   one     0.950088  0.443863
      two    -0.151357  0.333674

df.loc[('bar', "one"), 0] = 1
print df
                     0         1
first second                    
bar   one     1.000000 -0.103219
      two     0.400157  0.410599
baz   one     0.978738  0.144044
      two     2.240893  1.454274
foo   one     1.867558  0.761038
      two    -0.977278  0.121675
qux   one     0.950088  0.443863
      two    -0.151357  0.333674
```

If you need set all rows in level `second` with value `one` use `slice(None)`:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), "one"), 0] = 1
print df
                     0         1
first second                    
bar   one     1.000000 -0.103219
      two     0.400157  0.410599
baz   one     1.000000  0.144044
      two     2.240893  1.454274
foo   one     1.000000  0.761038
      two    -0.977278  0.121675
qux   one     1.000000  0.443863
      two    -0.151357  0.333674
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers).