# Setting values of multiindex dataframe using only one-level indexing

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

My question is a logical continuation of this topic:
[Setting values with multiindex in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989552/setting-values-with-multiindex-in-pandas). So the example and answer from this, suits my situation either.

They set a multiindex value with `f.loc[(slice(None), "one"), 0] = 1`

**But in my case,** i have lot's of dataframes with **custom number of  index levels**, so i would like to use indexing only on last level, without specifying others - smth like `f.loc[:::, "one"), 0] = 1`. 
P.S. Also, if i have an `Indexer` for column "one", am i able to use it?
Indexer can be an array: `array([ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you want to use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html):

```
In [276]: df
Out[276]:
                     0         1
first second
bar   one     0.414213 -0.316333
      two     1.109279  0.307283
baz   one    -0.287986 -1.963492
      two     0.858867  0.553895
foo   one    -0.152813 -2.489409
      two     1.022960  0.377656
qux   one     1.549389 -0.307250
      two    -1.150914 -3.517356

In [277]: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,'one'], 0] = 1

In [278]: df
Out[278]:
                     0         1
first second
bar   one     1.000000 -0.316333
      two     1.109279  0.307283
baz   one     1.000000 -1.963492
      two     0.858867  0.553895
foo   one     1.000000 -2.489409
      two     1.022960  0.377656
qux   one     1.000000 -0.307250
      two    -1.150914 -3.517356
```

boolean indexing using `mask`:

```
In [291]: mask = (df[0] > 1).values

In [292]: mask
Out[292]: array([False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [293]: df.loc[mask]
Out[293]:
                     0         1
first second
bar   two     1.109279  0.307283
foo   two     1.022960  0.377656

In [294]: df.iloc[mask]
Out[294]:
                     0         1
first second
bar   two     1.109279  0.307283
foo   two     1.022960  0.377656

In [295]: df[mask]
Out[295]:
                     0         1
first second
bar   two     1.109279  0.307283
foo   two     1.022960  0.377656
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please add info for the `P.S.`

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav, sorry, i don't understand that P.S. part. What is your `Indexer` and how do you want to use it?

Comment: It's just a mask. For example: `array([ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)`