# Replacing values in a 2nd level column on MultiIndex df in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was looking into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002197/pandas-proper-way-to-set-values-based-on-condition-for-subset-of-multiindex-da) which almost solved my problem. However, in my case, I want to work based on the 2nd level of the df, but trying not to specify my 1st level column names explicitly.

Borrowing the original dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('A','a'): [-1,-1,0,10,12],
                   ('A','b'): [0,1,2,3,-1],
                   ('B','a'): [-20,-10,0,10,20],
                   ('B','b'): [-200,-100,0,100,200]})

##df
    A   B
    a   b   a   b
0   -1  0   -20 -200
1   -1  1   -10 -100
2   0   2   0   0
3   10  3   10  100
4   12  -1  20  200
```

I want to assign `NA` to all columns `a` and `b` where `b<0`. I was selecting them based on: `df.xs('b',axis=1,level=1)<b`, but then I cannot actually perform the replace. However, I have varying 1st level names, so the indexing there cannot be made based on `A` and `B` explicitly, but possibly through `df.columns.values`?

The desired output would be

```
##df
    A   B
    a   b   a   b
0   -1  0   NA  NA
1   -1  1   NA  NA
2   0   2   0   0
3   10  3   10  100
4   NA  NA  20  200
```

I appreciate all tips, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same index and column names as original `DataFrame` created by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mask = df.xs('b',axis=1,level=1) < 0
print (mask)
       A      B
0  False   True
1  False   True
2  False  False
3  False  False
4   True  False

print (mask.reindex(columns = df.columns, level=0))
       A             B       
       a      b      a      b
0  False  False   True   True
1  False  False   True   True
2  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False
4   True   True  False  False

df = df.mask(mask.reindex(columns = df.columns, level=0))
print (df)
      A          B       
      a    b     a      b
0  -1.0  0.0   NaN    NaN
1  -1.0  1.0   NaN    NaN
2   0.0  2.0   0.0    0.0
3  10.0  3.0  10.0  100.0
4   NaN  NaN  20.0  200.0
```

*Edit by OP*: I had asked in comments how to consider multiple conditions (e.g. `df.xs('b',axis=1,level=1) < 0` OR `df.xs('b',axis=1,level=1)` being an `NA`).  @Jezrael kindly indicated that if I wanted to do this, I should consider

```
mask=(df.xs('b',axis=1,level=1) < 0 | df.xs('b',axis=1,level=1).isnull())
```