# Adding level to middle of DF in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a new level to my DF (so that then I can use `pd.reindex` to do something else). My DF basically has something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('A','a'): [-1,-1,0,10,12],
                   ('A','b'): [0,1,2,3,-1],
                   ('A','c'): [-1,1,0,10,12],
                   ('A','d'): [1,1,2,3,-1],
                   ('B','a'): [-20,-10,0,10,20],
                   ('B','b'): [-200,-100,0,-1,200],
                   ('B','c'): [-20,-10,0,10,20],
                   ('B','d'): [-200,-100,0,100,200]
})

##df
    A               B
    a   b   c   d   a   b     c     d
0   -1  0   1   1   -20 -200  -20   -200
1   -1  1   -1  1   -10 -100  -10   -100
2   0   2   0   2   0   0     0     0
3   10  3   10  3   10  -1    10    100
4   12  -1  12  -1  20  200   20    200
```

I want to assign new level keys `L1` = `a`+`b`, and `L2`=`c`+`d`. How do I do this?

The desired output would be

```
##df
    A               B
    L1      L2      L1        L2
    a   b   c   d   a   b     c     d
0   -1  0   1   1   -20 -200  -20   -200
1   -1  1   -1  1   -10 -100  -10   -100
2   0   2   0   2   0   0     0     0
3   10  3   10  3   10  -1    10    100
4   12  -1  12  -1  20  200   20    200
```

**Edit: the objective** is to achieve something similar to what was asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246373/replacing-values-in-a-2nd-level-column-on-multiindex-df-in-pandas). This means that some rows will have `NA`s for the same KEY, depending on the value of other columns. 
E.g. if I want to filter columns `a` and `c` by respectively testing whether columns `b` and `d` are negative:

```
##df
    A               B
    L1      L2      L1        L2
    a   b   c   d   a   b     c     d
0   -1  0   1   1   NA  NA    NA    NA
1   -1  1   -1  1   NA  NA    NA    NA
2   0   2   0   2   0   0     0     0
3   10  3   10  3   NA  NA    10    100
4   NA  NA  NA  NA  20  200   20    200
```

Comment: "so that then I can use pd.reindex to do something else": perhaps we can help you better if you state what is your final purpose.

Comment: Well, the final purpose is very similar to what I had asked in here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246373/replacing-values-in-a-2nd-level-column-on-multiindex-df-in-pandas). The difference now is that I have to do the parsing of columns `a` and `b` (as I did in the previous post), and the same for `c` and `d`.

Comment: I'm going to change the working example to reflect this comment

Comment: @Wli I have added some information which I hope may help in assisting me :)

Comment: It seems someone could answer it nevertheless :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need create new `array` with `map` and then assign:

```
d = {'a':'L1','b':'L1','c':'L2','d':'L2'}
a = df.columns.get_level_values(1).map(lambda x: d[x])
print (a)
['L1' 'L1' 'L2' 'L2' 'L1' 'L1' 'L2' 'L2']

df.columns = [df.columns.get_level_values(0),a,df.columns.get_level_values(1)]
#same as
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.get_level_values(0),
                                        df.columns.get_level_values(1).map(lambda x: d[x]),
                                        df.columns.get_level_values(1)])
print (df)
    A             B              
   L1     L2     L1       L2     
    a  b   c  d   a    b   c    d
0  -1  0  -1  1 -20 -200 -20 -200
1  -1  1   1  1 -10 -100 -10 -100
2   0  2   0  2   0    0   0    0
3  10  3  10  3  10   -1  10  100
4  12 -1  12 -1  20  200  20  200
```

Second output is really complicated, for me works:

```
#filter columns
idx = pd.IndexSlice
mask = df.loc[:, idx[:,:,['b','d']]] < 0
print (mask)
       A             B       
      L1     L2     L1     L2
       b      d      b      d
0  False  False   True   True
1  False  False   True   True
2  False  False  False  False
3  False  False   True  False
4   True   True  False  False

#create mask to columns a,c
mask1 = mask.reindex(columns=df.columns)
mask1 = mask1.groupby(level=[0,1], axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.bfill(axis=1))
print (mask1)
       A                           B                     
      L1            L2            L1            L2       
       a      b      c      d      a      b      c      d
0  False  False  False  False   True   True   True   True
1  False  False  False  False   True   True   True   True
2  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False   True   True  False  False
4   True   True   True   True  False  False  False  False

print (df.mask(mask1))
      A                     B                    
     L1         L2         L1           L2       
      a    b     c    d     a      b     c      d
0  -1.0  0.0  -1.0  1.0   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
1  -1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
2   0.0  2.0   0.0  2.0   0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0
3  10.0  3.0  10.0  3.0   NaN    NaN  10.0  100.0
4   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  20.0  200.0  20.0  200.0
```

---

Another solution with `reindex` and `method='bfill'`, but is necessary double transpose (I think it is bug - works only with `MultiIndex` in `index`, not with `MultiIndex` in `columns`):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
mask = df.loc[:, idx[:,['b','d']]] < 0
print (mask)
       A             B       
       b      d      b      d
0  False  False   True   True
1  False  False   True   True
2  False  False  False  False
3  False  False   True  False
4   True   True  False  False

mask1 = mask.T.reindex(df.columns, method='bfill').T
print (mask1)
       A                           B                     
       a      b      c      d      a      b      c      d
0  False  False  False  False   True   True   True   True
1  False  False  False  False   True   True   True   True
2  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False   True   True  False  False
4   True   True   True   True  False  False  False  False

print (df.mask(mask1))
      A                     B                    
      a    b     c    d     a      b     c      d
0  -1.0  0.0  -1.0  1.0   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
1  -1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
2   0.0  2.0   0.0  2.0   0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0
3  10.0  3.0  10.0  3.0   NaN    NaN  10.0  100.0
4   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  20.0  200.0  20.0  200.0
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when setting `mask = df.loc[:, idx[:,:,['b','d']]] < 0`: `KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (3), lexsort depth (2)'`. Changing your `mask` to `mask = df.loc[:, idx[:,['b','d']]] < 0` solves the problem with your working example and yields the correct `print`. However, in my real example I also get a similar error `the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (3), lexsort depth (1)'`, and I am not able to solve it and get the correct print

Comment: I think you need `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)` first, check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex)

Comment: Thank you so much @jezrael, I learned a lot with this and your previous answer to my post! I am truly grateful!

Comment: MultiIndexes are really hard, this question is not so nice because there is a hack - `groupby` with `bfill`, but i have no idea how do it better.