# How to use .apply function on a pandas DataFrame that has been filtered by regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with data scraped from a couple Wiki tables. The DataFrame has a column for names and some of these names are followed by "\r\n(head coach)". I would like to remove that and so I tried this:

```
df['name'][df.name.str.contains(r'coach')] =\
df['name'][df.name.str.contains(r'coach')].apply(lambda x: x[0:-14])
```

When this runs, I get a SettingWithCopyWarning. I tried using .loc as suggested in this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002197/pandas-proper-way-to-set-values-based-on-condition-for-subset-of-multiindex-da):

```
 mask = df.loc[:,'name'] == df['name'].str.contains(r'coach')
```

But every value returns as False and so I get an empty Series when I use this with my DataFrame.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong with this. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
mask = df.name.str.contains(r'coach')]
df.loc[mask, 'name'] = df.loc[mask, 'name'].str[:-14]
```

Or as @piRSquared commented, this simple line should also work:

```
df.loc[mask, 'name'] = df.name.str[:-14]
```

Comment: you don't need to mask twice.  `df.name.str[:-14]`

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast. Thanks so much!