# Error: Truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I want to create conditions as below to evaluate the *HUB Status* as ...

1. CUR_RULE=DEFAULT and PREV_RULE=DEFAULT, then **ok**.
2. CUR_RULE=DEFAULT and PREV_RULE!=DEFAULT, then **not ok**.
3. CUR_RULE!=DEFAULT and PREV_RULE=DEFAULT, then **ok**.
4. CUR_RULE!=DEFAULT and PREV_RULE!=DEFAULT, then **ok**.

I am trying to run the code below:

```python
df3=df1[df1['STATUS']=='CHANGED']
df3.insert(7, 'HUB STATUS','')
df3.insert(8, 'COMMENT','')
if df3[df3['CUR_RULE']=='DEFAULT'] and df3[df3['PREV_RULE']=='DEFAULT']:
    df3['HUB STATUS']='OK'
elif df3[df3['CUR_RULE']=='DEFAULT'] and df3[df3['PREV_RULE']!='DEFAULT']:
    df3['HUB STATUS']='NOT OK'
elif df3[df3['CUR_RULE']!='DEFAULT'] and df3[df3['PREV_RULE']=='DEFAULT']:
    df3['HUB STATUS']='OK'
else:
    df3['HUB STATUS']='NOT OK'
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: add pandas tag, if you actually areusing pandas module

Comment: To properly respond to your request, please provide a sample of your input dataframe.  The immediate cause of your error seems to be in the following line of code and the other places where you use similar structure:  ```df3[df3['CUR_RULE']=='DEFAULT'] ```  The issue is that the factor to the left of the == is a panda series, not a single value, yet you are trying to compare to a single value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical operators for boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue: no truth values inside index

In vanilla Python logical boolean expressions can use `or` and `and`, which require truth-values on each side. Along with comparisons like `==` or `!=` these form valid expressions to be used inside if-statements.

But when used inside panda's dataframe indexes (square brackets to select one column) they are invalid. Like the index attempt
`df3[df3['CUR_RULE']=='DEFAULT']` which contains a boolean condition inside square brackets `df3['CUR_RULE']=='DEFAULT'`.

For *pandas* these *index* expressions evaluates to a truth value which is considered **ambiguous**.

#### Filter: using bitwise operators inside conditions

Instead you could use **bitwise operations**:

- `|` (or)
- `&` (and)

See [Difference between 'and' and '&' in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-and-in-python/)

For example when applying *filters* with panda's `where`, like:

```py
# filtering data
df3.where(df3['CUR_RULE'] == 'DEFAULT' & df3['PREV_RULE'] == 'DEFAULT', inplace=True)
print(df3) # show series filtered for df3['HUB STATUS']='OK'
```

See [Pandas where: How to Use Pandas DataFrame where()](https://appdividend.com/2020/08/06/how-to-use-pandas-dataframe-where/)

#### Map: using a ternary (similar to if-else)

or better using the [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function, like here using a lambda:

```py
# mapping data using a function, dict, or lambda
map_hub = lambda x: 'NOT OK' if x['CUR_RULE'] == 'DEFAULT' and x['PREV_RULE'] != 'DEFAULT' else 'OK' 

df3['HUB STATUS'] = df3.map(map_hub)
```

See
[Adding a new pandas column with mapped value from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216425/adding-a-new-pandas-column-with-mapped-value-from-a-dictionary)

#### See also

- [Pandas : Proper way to set values based on condition for subset of multiindex dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002197/pandas-proper-way-to-set-values-based-on-condition-for-subset-of-multiindex-da)